# Single “Multiple Inputs Tx” vs Multiple “Single Input Tx”

Tags: cluster-analysis, bitcoin, privacy

Alice owns three addresses `A1`, `A2`, `A3`. She decides to collect the coins held by these addresses into a single coin so she generates *a fresh new address* `A4` for that.

She has the following two options:

**1. Single transaction**

`+--------------+
 |A1          A4|
 |A2    ->      |
 |A3            |
 +--------------+`

**2. Multiple transactions**

`+--------------+
 |A1          A4|
 +--------------+`

`+--------------+
 |A2          A4|
 +--------------+`

`+--------------+
 |A3          A4|
 +--------------+`

---

She does not want people to know that `A1`, `A2` and `A3` are owned by her. And she does not intend to use any mixing services. She also don't mind paying more transaction fees as in option 2.

### Option 1

`A1`, `A2` and `A3` can be linked together assuming she did not use any [Coin Join](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=279249.0) technique.

### Option 2

It can be seen that `A4` is reused to receive payments. However `A4` has never been seen before this transaction.

#### Questions on Option 2:

1. Can someone observing the Blockchain **deterministically** figure out `A1`, `A2` and `A3` belong to same user?
2. If Alice now spends `A4` to Bob (sends all amount, she never uses `A4` again), can Bob ever figure out that `A1`, `A2` and `A3` belonged to Alice?
3. What privacy will Alice (or someone down the trail, like Bob) lose if she goes for option 2?
4. Is reusing addresses to only receive payments and spending that address only once okay?

Comment: This question is not about programming. You may be able to get help on our sister site [bitcoin.se].

Answer (score -1):

1. I don't think so without any extra knowledge.
2. Same as above.
3. Option 2 looks more anonymous because Option 1 shows that A1, A2 and A3 know about each other enough to be able to transact together.
4. That is very common scenario and recommended by many wallets.